# Convert a wma to wav programatically with Windows Media Encoder

Tags: audio, wma, windows-media-encoder

Has anyone converted a WMA to a WAV using Windows Media Encoder?  If so, do you have a short code snippet of how you did it?  All samples I've seen have been for WAV to WMA, not the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that all of the samples you've seen have been for WAV to WMA is that you're looking at Windows Media **Encoder**. You want to **decode** WMA to WAV. Look at the [Windows Media Format SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387410.aspx) instead.